# How can I create a new DataGridView control for each new row in another datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control (DataGridView6) that displays a list of managers. I want to generate a new `DataGridView` everytime I add a new manager to the list and put it in a specific place on my form.

**EDIT:**

say if i have a main datagridview, and i want to add another datagridview of the same size directly below it, how would i achieve this using the event handler method described in your answer below? im not sure if this is the most efficient way of displaying new members in the program though...

How do can I do this as simply as possible?

Comment: how are you populating DataGridView6 in the first place?

Comment: as the tags suggest, i am using a mysql database as the datasource for my datagridview6. and i want to create a new datagridview for each new manager added to the list.

Comment: are you kidding? usually people answer my questions right away but ive waited over 2 weeks.... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DataGridView's "RowsAdded" event. Every time you add a new row (ie manager) to DataGridView6, have the event handler create a new DataGridView and place it where you want it.

It's hard to give a more detailed answer without the specifics of your implementation, but something like that should work.

EDIT - So something like this?

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Location = new Point(DataGridView6.Location.X,DataGridView6.Location.Y + <somevalue>);
```

If you need to keep adding them below this, you could just make a variable NextY that you increment each time you add a new one. You can store them all in a LinkedList or something similar so you can access them easily in order.

Comment: ive updated my post with more information. the bounty expires in three days... :/

Comment: that is perfect thanks! so how would i go about getting the x y coordinates of where i want to place the new datagridview? is there a simple script i could write that would show the current coordinates of where i point my mouse?

Comment: ok so i can get the mouse coordinates, but only when hovering over the form itself. but the controls on that form are blocking it. is there a way to disregard the controls and just get the mouse position?

Comment: Try System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at VB, so I've written it in C# first:

```
DataGridView DataGridView6;
DataGridView DataGridView7;

DataGridViewRow CreateRow(object data) {
  DataGridViewRow row = null;
  int index = DataGridView6.Rows.Add();
  row = DataGridView6.Rows[index];
  // row.Cells[0] = something;
  // basically, add your date
  return row;
}

void DisplayManagerRow(DataGridViewRow row) {
  DataGridView7.DataSource = null;
  int columns = (DataGridView6.Columns != null) ? DataGridView6.Columns.Count : 0;
  if ((row != null) && (0 < columns)) {
    DataGridView7.Columns.Clear();
    List<DataGridViewColumn> cols = new List<DataGridViewColumn>(columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
      DataGridViewColumn dgvCol = (DataGridViewColumn)DataGridView6.Columns[i].Clone();
      DataGridView7.Columns.Add(dgvCol);
    }
    DataGridView7.Rows.Add(row);
  }
}
```

Now, to try this in VB:

```
private DataGridView6 As DataGridView
private DataGridView7 As DataGridView

Private Function CreateRow(ByVal data As Object) As DataGridViewRow
  Dim index As Int16 = DataGridView6.Rows.Add()
  Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView6.Rows(index)
  ' row.Cells(0) = something
  ' basically, add your date
  Return row
End Function

Private Sub DisplayManagerRow(ByVal row As DataGridViewRow)
  DataGridView7.DataSource = Nothing
  Dim columns As Int32 = 0
  If Not (DataGridView6.Columns = Nothing) Then
    columns = DataGridView6.Columns.Count
  End If
  If ((row Is Not Nothing) And (0 < columns)) Then
    DataGridView7.Columns.Clear()
    Dim cols As List<DataGridViewColumn> = new List<DataGridViewColumn>(columns)
    For (Dim i As Int32 = 0; i < columns; i++) 
      Dim dgvCol As DataGridViewColumn = CType(DataGridView6.Columns(i).Clone(), DataGridViewColumn)
      DataGridView7.Columns.Add(dgvCol)
    Next For
    DataGridView7.Rows.Add(row)
  End If
End Sub
```

I can't even remember how to write a For loop in VB! Pathetic!

Does that get the point across, though?

Is this what you are trying to do?